# How do I submit a bug to launchpad without internet

Tags: networking, bug-reporting

As you may have guessed, I need to report a bug pertaining to not having internet to launchpad. Whenever I go to "Report a bug", I am taken to this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Looking through that page, it looks like I need internet to report bugs that way.

Also: I made this post using my laptop.

Thank you

Comment: For internet-not-working, it's usually worthwhile to run it by AskUbuntu first. There are many common causes that just require a tweak or two.

Comment: @user535733 should I repost this question there?

Comment: No, you received several good answers to "*How do I file a bug report*." You should ask for troubleshooting help for your real problem "there." Um you realize that *this* is AskUbuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The page that you linked has instructions under the headers [Filing bugs when offline or using a headless setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_when_offline_or_using_a_headless_setup) and [Filing bugs manually at Launchpad.net](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_manually_at_Launchpad.net):**

> **Filing bugs when offline or using a headless setup**
>
> In the event that you have an issue with your internet connection,
> want to file a bug for another system, or have trouble reporting from
> a headless setup, you can still do this using apport.
>
> For a bug report about a crash, copy over the .crash file created in
> the /var/crash folder to the new computer. Then report it from the new
> computer via a terminal:
>
> ```
> ubuntu-bug FILENAME.crash
> ```
>
> For a bug report about any other issue, from the computer with the
> problem execute the following at a terminal:
>
> ```
> apport-cli -f -p PACKAGENAME --save FILENAME.apport
> ```
>
> Copy this over to the new computer. If filing a new report, execute
> via a terminal:
>
> ```
> ubuntu-bug FILENAME.apport
> ```
>
> Please do not attach the .apport or .crash file to the report, as this
> is not the same as performing the above mentioned steps.
>
> **Filing bugs manually at Launchpad.net**
>
> If for some reason you cannot file a bug using the Apport tool you can
> file one via [Launchpad's own bug report
> form](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect). When
> doing so it is best if you have determined which package it should be
> filed against. Read '[finding the right
> package](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage)' for guidance
> or use [Launchpad's package search
> feature](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/). We don't recommend this method
> for most bug reports because they will likely be missing crucial
> information, use ubuntu-bug if you can!
>
> To file a bug against a specific package you can also use a URL like
> the following:
>
> ```
> http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/PACKAGENAME/+filebug?no-redirect
> ```
>
> where PACKAGENAME is the name of the source package about which you
> want to file the bug report.
>
> In the event that you want to request a piece of software be packaged
> for Ubuntu please follow the instructions in the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages#Requesting%20a%20new%20package%20for%20Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

I am of course perplexed that you're complaining about being unable to report a bug about Ubuntu because you need an Internet connection, whilst making a report about that, clearly with an Internet connection. Well done! :D

However, it's not unreasonable to have no Internet connect on the machine with the problem, and needing to file the issue from another machine, as it appears you have done here.

As such, you can construct a URL using: https://launchpad.net/ ubuntu / +source / (packagename) / +filebug

(assuming you know the package name - which you don't mention)

This should take you to a form in which you can specify the problem, some detail regarding the ways to reproduce the issue and any pertinent details.

Comment: I think the OP is using a different computer than the one with the problem, in order to post this question. Additionally, as you know, the report bug dialog that pops up also includes a stack trace from that specific machine with the problem. Could the OP copy that stack trace to a USB, and then manually attach it to the new bug report, created using your suggestion above?

Comment: @PJSingh yeah I can try that

Comment: @PJSingh I ran the `ubuntu-bug` command and then selected the `dist-upgrade` one cuz I recently upgraded from 18 to 20. I then got this screen: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/653633559206166541/782053114089439242/20201127_201820.jpg?width=1382&height=672

Edit: I tried "Send", but it then says "Cannot connect to crash database, please check your internet connection." I can't seem to find anywhere where I can copy and paste to my thumb drive.

Comment: If this helps any, here is a question I posted on the unix stack exchange that has to do with my internet problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621883/cannot-use-usb-tethering-to-solve-problem?noredirect=1#comment1163154_621883

Comment: I think if you create the bug report using your laptop, you can just copy and attach the `*.crash` file from `/var/crash`. (It's probably the most recent crash file; also the name of the file should let you know which package crashed).

Comment: @PJSingh I found a file called "_usr_libexec_tracker-store.1000.crash". Would the `(packagename)` in the URL be "libexec"?

Comment: The package is probably "tracker". (See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tracker-store&mode=exactfilename&suite=groovy&arch=any)